# MenuItem.Icon not greyed out with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to show a different image as menuitem.icon if the menuitem is disabled (just a greyed out version). This is what I tried:

```
<tk:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="_Divorce" Command="{Binding Path=DivorceCommand}">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image>
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem, AncestorLevel=3}}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="eraser.ico" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem, AncestorLevel=3}}" Value="false"
                                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="eraser_grey.ico" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>   
        </MenuItem.Icon>  
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>  
</tk:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</tk:DataGrid>
```

Error message:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsEnabled; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

What is wrong with my current XAML datatrigger binding?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

Add a Trigger like [CubaLibre mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608352/menuitem-icon-not-greyed-out-with-datatrigger/6608698#6608698)

But instead of using a target name, which will not work. Use the following.

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
   <Setter TargetName="Image">
       <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="eraser_grey.ico"/>
       </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

if that will not work (sorry can't test it for myself at the moment). You could also do it the hard way:

Create a Style for menuitem, you can just completely copy the [original style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
Now in the control template, of the desired role template, you just add under ControlTemplate.Triggers. Your trigger like

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
  <Setter Property="Source" Value="eraser_grey.ico"/>
</Trigger>
```

to make it a little bit cleaner. I would add a service class, which contains an attached property named "DisabledIcon" or similiar and use that as an value, instead the hard coded one.

Unfortunately changing the whole style is the only working way i can think of right now.

[Edit]

Ok after some further investigation, here is a solution that works fine, even though i'm not happy with it because it is quiet ugly :( But sorry i have no better idea at the moment.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Divorce" Command="...">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image x:Name="iconImage" Source="arrowDown.png"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="iconImage" Property="Source" Value="close.png"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: To which element in my XAML do I have to add the '<Trigger>'? I tried to add it under '<MenuItem>' which doesnt work. Sorry for my noobiness...

Comment: I changed my answer mit a working solution, see if that works for you aswell.

Comment: Vielen Dank, jetzt klappt es wunderbar :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
   <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="Image" Value="eraser_grey.ico"/>
</Trigger>
```

Does it work when you try to do so

Comment: How can I include your code into my example? I've got a datatrigger, in your example there is a simple Trigger. If I replace your Setter with mine I receive error 'Target property cannot be set on a style setter'.

Comment: You need to do the trigger on the ControlTemplate.Trigger item of the MenuItem. Here is an example how the menu style can be customized: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx